# Multiple processes writing shared memory

Tags: c, memory, posix, shared

I have to write a program with multiple processes writing a string taken by standard input in shared memory without overwriting the strings previously added. When the father receives the signal SIGINT prints all the strings put into the shared memory. The problem is that it doesn't behave as expected, can anyone help me?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#define MAXSIZE 50

int n; 
char *at;
int *p;

void handler(int sig){

    printf("Received signal %d\n", sig);
    printf("Printinf all the data in the shared memory\n");

    printf("At1 è uguale: %d\n", n);

    while(*p != -1){

        printf("%s\n", at);
        at = at -MAXSIZE;
        *p = *p-1;
        printf("Valore di p: %d\n", *p);

    }

    exit(1);

}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

    if(argc != 2){

        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s numberOfProcesses\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);

    }

    sem_t *sem;
    sem = sem_open("femaforo", O_CREAT, 0664, 1);
    if(sem == SEM_FAILED){

        perror("Error while creating semaphore\n");
        exit(-1);

    }

    n = atoi(argv[1]);

    pid_t pid, wpid;

    key_t key = 1411;
    key_t key1 = 788;

    /*int shmid = shmget(key, 1024, IPC_CREAT | 0644);
    if(shmid < 0){

        perror("Error while creating shared memory\n");
        exit(-1);

    }*/


    at = (char *)mmap(NULL, 1024, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
    if(at == (void *)-1){

        perror("Error while attaching memory\n");
        exit(-1);

    }
    int shmid2 = shmget(key1, sizeof(int), 0644 | IPC_CREAT);
    if(shmid2 < 0){

        perror("Error while creating second memory\n");
        exit(-1);

    }

    p = (int *)shmat(shmid2, NULL,0);
    if(p == (void *)-1){

        perror("Error while attaching second memory\n");
        exit(-1);

    }

    *p = 0;


    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

        pid = fork();

        if(pid == 0){

            printf("I am a process with pid: %d\n", getpid());
            break;

        }else if(pid < 0){

            perror("Error while creating a process\n");
            exit(-1);

        }


    }

    if(pid == 0){//figlio

        sem_wait(sem);

        printf("In at c'è: %s\n", at);

        char string[MAXSIZE];

        printf("Insert a string for the shared memory\n");
        scanf("%s", string);
        strcpy(at, string);

        at = at +MAXSIZE;

        *p = *p +1;

        printf("Value of p is: %d\n", *p);

        sem_post(sem);

    }else{ //padre

        sigset_t set;
        sigfillset(&set);
        sigdelset(&set, SIGINT);
        struct sigaction act;

        act.sa_mask = set;
        act.sa_handler = handler;

        sigaction(SIGINT, &act, 0);

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){

            wpid = wait(NULL);


        }

        handler(0);

        printf("I am the father and I am exiting\n");

        exit(1);


    }

}
```

Comment: What did you input? What did you expect to happen? What actually happens?

Comment: As input simple strings, the father process prints only the last string put into the memory. I want to print every string previously put